# Dijkstra's algorithm on huge graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I am very familiar with Dijkstra and I have a specific question about the algorithm. If I have a huge graph, for example 3.5 billion nodes (all OpenStreetMap data) then I clearly wouldn't be able to have the graph in memory, so the graph is stored on disk in a database.

There are libraries available to compute shortest paths on such graphs. How do they do this? More specifically, how do they load the required part of the graph to run Dijkstra's algorithm?

Fetching the adjacency list of each vertex visited would require about 1,500 database queries per 10,000 nodes according to my statistical data, so that clearly is not how they do it. That would be way too slow.

How do they do it? I am trying to implement it myself.

Comment: Are you sure they use Dijkstra? There are plenty of other shortest path algorithms that may be better suited to the situation you describe.

Comment: Have you looked into the code? How should we know? "database queries" -- I hope you don't use a DBMS for storing graphs?

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes I am sure, look at [this link](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/dijkstra.html)

Comment: @Raphael I am referring to `SpatiaLite` library which supports spatial data. Its not as simple as "look into the code" because the API works by doing queries to the database, and the result is the shortest path. Look at [this link](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/dijkstra.html) . To "look into the code" I would have to see how the queries are parsed, and it would be an extremely tedious process to look into pure C code.

Comment: "[I]t would be an extremely tedious process to look into pure C code." But that's the only way of knowing what the code does. So you're just asking us to do your tedious task for you, which isn't the greatest ad for your question...

Comment: @DavidRicherby The code is barely readable. I think that people who are familiar with this problem will know the answer no matter how `SpatiaLite` implements it

Comment: @Shiro You explicitly ask, "How do they do this?" If that's not really the question you want to ask, you need to rephrase.

Comment: how about post the link to the code if you know it. comments sometimes reveal basic info

Comment: found [it](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/artifact/d2b21b07c24a15ed840385e0f9cc5c7868e411f4), its by Luigi Costalli

Comment: may try to answer this but the implementation you mention in the comment, SpatiaLite, looks like it uses an entirely in-memory algorithm. more ref to OpenStreetMap db and/or any algorithms known to work on it would be helpful. the general area is known as "online graph algorithms" where online refers to not all data stored in memory simultaneously ie/ aka disk storage. the short answer is that the algorithm runs "in the db" without actually "querying" data in the typical higher-level "SQL" sense, it scans the internal binary tables.

Comment: Have you tried Boost Library help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are libraries available to compute shortest paths on such graphs. How do they do this? More specifically, how do they load the required part of the graph to run Dijkstra's algorithm?

You can use a DB, a custom file format to be read from disc and an in-memory setting.

But from my experience using a DB is roughly 5 to 10 times slower and a lot more memory intense than writing your own file format based on a 'simple' linked list format.

The good thing is there are several software frameworks using OSM which are open source so you can look right into the code e.g. see [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing). In the [GraphHopper open source routing engine](https://graphhopper.com/) it is very easy to switch from a memory mapped setting (disc based) to the in-memory setting - both using the same format. The "mmap" setting even allows usage on memory restricted mobile devices and the latter performs a lot faster if you have the necessary RAM e.g. on a server. E.g. for a world wide graph (>100mio nodes) you then need around 8-10gb RAM, plus lot of more RAM if you want to speed up everything further e.g. with Contraction Hierarchies - roughly 5-8gb more for every vehicle you want.

The format is very simplistic and basically stores only the data you need with a few tricks to make it compact. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/technical.md#2-the-graph). Disclaimer: I'm the author of GraphHopper.

Regarding the other answers:

> Dijkstras algorithm while applicable is regarded as not optimal for this problem

The 'normal' Dijkstra can perform very reasonable (<1s for country-wide queries like your 3mio nodes example) and is **optimal** in the 'theory sense' but needs a bit tuning to get fast in production scenarios. And techniques like Contraction Hierachies use a bidirectional modification of it and perform very well.

> road networks are hierarchical and planar.

road networks are hierarchical for car only and not planar (bridges, tunnels, ...)

Comment: I have one more question. How do you find the `NodeID` of the closest node from the `latitude/longitude` ? That is required to calculate shortest path A->B. And also we need to keep in mind that the A and B might not exist as nodes, because not every square meter contains a node. So we need to find the 2 closest NodeIDs of A and B.

Comment: That is done in the LocationIndexTree which is kind of a quadtree storing efficiently the NodeIDs in a cell which has e.g. for GraphHopper a radius of ~500m. If nothing is found it expands the radius up to a certain degree. This sounds simple in theory but is very complex as you might have edges crossing the area, you need to be efficient when creating and querying it and a lot more.

Comment: Aren't KD-Trees more efficient when searching for the nearest neighbor ? Why did you chose QuadTrees over KD-Trees ? I am implementing KD-Trees for my routing engine right now. I started implementing QuadTrees but I stopped because I figured that KD-Trees is the same thing, but easier to code, and faster to query the nearest neighbor. Am I wrong ?

Comment: When using quadtrees there is no need to explicitely store the the bounding box giving it a storage advantage, which was more critical for my usecase (also I find quadtrees easier ;)). Query speed is not an issue. In fact someone studied such tries and it outperformed any other implementations incl. KD trees, but I assume all depends on the specific implementation...

Comment: If you look at page 9 of [this pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/handouts/assignment-3-kdtree.pdf) from stanford, searching for nearest neighbor in KD-Trees doesn't require you to know the bounding boxes at all. And another thing is that because we know all the points beforehand, we can create a balanced tree of logn height. Are still you positive that quadtrees have any advantage over kd-trees ?

Comment: Both are very similar except that KD trees do store their data more flexible (but they require the bbox to be **stored** in the tree somewhere which should be only a minor disadvantage). I still think they are slightly more complex to implement but giving my dynamic leaf-count implementation in GraphHopper the KD tree would have been probably easier.

Comment: If you look at the page 9 of the link above, you can find the nearest neighbor with very little code because of recursion. The code is really not obvious at all. There is no need to know the bounding box. What you actually do is start from the root, then go left or right depending on the coordinates you are looking for. Then you are gonna hit a leaf. By now you will have computed a "best node" and a "best distance". Then, as the recursion returns, then you start checking if the OTHER node of the tree you are currently visiting could possibly contain a coordinate that is

Comment: closer to your "best guess". So, you don't need a bounding box. Instead you are checking only the X side or Y side each time depending on how the tree was split. And that check is checking if `|x - x'|` or `|y-y'|`is less than your "best distance" or not. My tree nodes contain only the NodeID and a pointer to the Left and Right child, since I can retrieve the LatLng information from an array which is indexed by the NodeID. So that is absolutely the minimum memory you could use. It is 150 lines of code, plus the tree is balanced, so exactly logn height

Comment: Basically in kd-tree instead of checking the bounds, you are actually checking 1 bound per time, depending on how you split (X or Y). And you know exactly where those bounds are because you are splitting the regions ON your coordinates, which can be retrieved from the array `latlngs[node_id]`

Comment: I don't get it as you need to store this 'bound value' somewhere but anyway: just try :) !

Comment: Each of the bounds would be `coordinates[nodeID].lat` or `coordinates[nodeID].lng`.  We check one at the time depending on if we split on X or Y axis each time. The property that we take advantage of is that we split ON our coordinates. There are no "buckets". And, we already have an array of `coordinates` indexed by nodeID will give us the LatLng

Comment: I managed to implement the KD Tree and I can query a node ID, given a lat,lng coordinate. The KD Tree is a binary tree, therefore it is implemented as an array. More specifically an array of integers with length of our nodes count, because I am storing only the Node IDs. However I have a huge problem. I want to query *edges*, not nodes. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892564/find-nearest-edge-in-graph) describes perfectly my problem. How did you manage to solve that problem ? Are quad trees able to query edges ?

Comment: I believe an algorithm I could follow to find the nearest edge is to do a range search in the KD Tree (search in a given rectangle). That rectangle will have to be big so that it includes the biggest edge (road segment) of the graph. Do you think that would be alright ?

Comment: As I can have cells of pre-defined size (at the leafs of the tree) I can solve it with the bresenham algo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679963/precise-subpixel-line-drawing-algorithm-rasterization-algorithm

Comment: Does this kind of geometry apply on Lat,Lng coordinates ? Don't you have to take into consideration that these points are projected ? Can you simply treat them as X and Y like that ?

Comment: You have to be aware of this as it is indeed a distorted cell but then it works IMO

Comment: I don't get how you use something like bresenham. You have the nodes in a quadtree. How do you get the nearest edge, from a given coordinate ? Could you please elaborate ? This is the last thing I need to complete my routing engine. Right now how I am planning on calculating the nearest edge from a coordinate is to do a range search on my KD Tree from the given coordinate, in a radius that is equal to the length of the longest edge. This way I will retrieve nodes, and from the nodes I will get edges, then calculate the closest edge. If quad tree works better I will make it. But I don't see how

Comment: I cannot comment on KD Tree ... but for a quadtree you basically have cells which you can fill via bresenham and on query you need to take into account that sometimes the surrounding cells are required. You can look into the code: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/storage/index/LocationIndexTree.java#L437

Comment: You are "filling cells via bresenham" ? Does that mean you have information for the edges on your quad tree ? So if an edge is inside 2 cells, you are saving that edge on all 2 cells ? I don't keep any edge information on my KD Tree. This is why I am planning on doing a range search with a radius that will guarentee to retrieve at least one of the two nodes of the nearest edge, so that I can then retrieve that edge from my edges collection, using that node. And that seems to be reasonable because roads segments are really small. Are you actually saving the edges on the quad tree ?

Comment: I mean that, if the longest road segment on the whole graph is 428 meters, then I will do a range search from the given coordinate for 428 meters, and guarantee to find at least one of the two nodes of the nearest edge. From that node, I will retrieve the edge using that node's ID as an index (from the collection that I use to store edges in) and voila. Nearest edge retrieved. Are you doing something similar ? Or are you saving the edges on the quad tree ?

Comment: You asked "So if an edge is inside 2 cells, you are saving that edge on all 2 cells ?" -> yes kind of but I'm just storing (edge or) node IDs and then I can fetch the node and edge properties from the graph. All very memory efficient

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to put all edges that are adjacent in the priority queue. "Lie" to Dijkstra's algorithm and give it only the shortest vertex, v,  incident to the vertex, say w, pulled off the stack. Then, when v is pulled of the queue you say "oops" I made  a mistake and should have given you this vertex too, which is the next closest to vertex w. It is easily seen that this way you will have a correct solution and the queue size is dramatically reduced to one incident vertex only instead of the many. You need though to keep track of the incidences to always give the next closest vertex - when required.
One of the comments claimed road networks are planar that is incorrect. In fact, a study has shown they are highly non-planar. Think of all motorways crossing via bridges through a city inducing many non-planarities.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstras algorithm while applicable is regarded as not optimal for this problem although more efficient variants could be considered as "similar". there are various simplifications. road networks are [hierarchical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_network_model) and [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph). here are the basic approaches. the area is generally known as "route planning in road networks".

- a graph structure can be "compiled" from the adjacency list data. this is the approach in the library you [cite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/dijkstra.html), SpatiaLite. these graph structures are stored in a compressed binary format where graph locations are represented by binary-encoded integers etc., so the graph representation and manipulation takes much less space than storing all the road names etc.; it appears the SpatiaLite algorithm is not "online" and runs entirely in memory.
- there are parallel/ distributed algorithms. see eg [Scalable GPU Graph Traversal](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS395T/2013fa/papers/garlandGPU.pdf) / Merrill, Garland, Grimshaw.
- the question uses client-server terminology ie "queries". the algorithms do not run by "querying" the database in the client-server sense. higher level query languages such as SQL are an interface to the database and may be used to transmit the request to compute the minimal routes but are not used by the algorithm internally. generally the algorithm runs "inside the database" ie entirely "server side". so hence writing a shortest path algorithm in database queries is feasible for small networks but not medium/ large scale ones.
- there is another approach where estimations within small percentages may be acceptable. the basic idea is to keep an index of distances between nodes. see eg [Fast and Accurate Estimation of Shortest Paths in Large Graphs](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~sseufert/papers/aspsn-cikm.pdf) / Gubichev, Bedathur, Seufert, Weikum
- this (235p!) Phd thesis is especially applicable. [Route Planning in Road Networks](https://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/schultes_diss.pdf) / Schultes
- some algorithms use many of these ideas and others, are highly tuned and proprietary and verging on competitive trade secrets. eg Google's. there may be some misleading media on this subject. eg [The Simple, Elegant Algorithm That Makes Google Maps Possible](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/the-simple-elegant-algorithm-that-makes-google-maps-possible) which claims/ implies Google uses Dijkstras algorithm without any citation.

Comment: Google Maps certainly has upgraded to something better than Dijskstra.  Every halfway competent developer would use A* for road maps, but at my previous job we found out that Google's engine could replan 2500 km routes via a waypoint in <100 ms. That's too fast for A*, so it's probable they use something like ArcFlags.

Comment: Karussell's answer challenges this opening sentence "Dijkstras algorithm while applicable is regarded as not optimal for this problem" which did not expect would be controversial. there is very strong support for the assertion in the Schultes thesis (early on) which is also a very comprehensive/ recent survey of the area, and also explains the "hierarchical and planar" "approximations". unfortunately there seems to be no indication of the actual google algorithms in open literature on cursory search.